# How to show a single calendar in react-dates?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, react-datepicker, react-dates

I need to integrate `SingleDatePicker` from react-dates.

This is what I have written in the code

```
<SingleDatePicker
    date={moment()} 
    onDateChange={date => this.setState({ date })} 
    focused={this.state.focused}
    onFocusChange={({ focused }) => this.setState({ focused })}
    id="your_unique_id"
/>
```

Now it shows me double calendar.

[image]

But I need to show only single. Something like this

[image]

Is there any option in the `SingleDatePicker` to do this?

Comment: lokk that :http://airbnb.io/react-dates/?selectedKind=SDP%20-%20Calendar%20Props&selectedStory=single%20month&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:

```
<SingleDatePicker
    date={moment()} 
    onDateChange={(date) => this.setState({ date })}
    numberOfMonths={1},
    focused={this.state.focused}
    onFocusChange={({ focused }) => this.setState({ focused })}
    id="your_unique_id"
/>
```